# Clustering correlated variables

Tags: correlation, clustering

I have a dataset with 10 variables. Three pairs of these variables are correlated. What happens if I add all of these variables in the clustering?

Does this depend on the type of clustering?

I found a question about this [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112277/correlated-variables-in-kmeans-clustering) but the answer there wasn't able to clear my questions.